# Windows RegQueryValueEx odd return results

Tags: windows, winapi, registry

I am getting odd results when using `RegQueryValueEx` and I cannot figure out why.

This is what I had set up before making the `RegQueryValueEx`

```
DWORD dataSize;
TCHAR data[256];
```

The first time I call

```
LONG ret = RegQueryValueEx( hKey, dataKey, NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)data, &dataSize);
```

`ret` is equal to 234 (`ERROR_MORE_DATA`)

But when I call the same thing on the next line

```
LONG ret2 = RegQueryValueEx( hKey, dataKey, NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)data, &dataSize);
```

`ret2` is equal to 0 (`ERROR_SUCCESS`)

Why would this function return `ERROR_MORE_DATA` the first time I call it, then return `ERROR_SUCESS` on the same call on the very next line?

I attempted to change `TCHAR data[1024]` but I got the exact same results. Any ideas?

Complete code:

```
for( int i=0; i<NUM_HISTORY; i++){
     CString dataKey = getDataKey(i);

     DWORD dataSize = 1024;
     TCHAR data[1024];

     LONG ret = RegQueryValueEx( hKey, dataKey, NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)data, &dataSize);
     LONG ret2 = RegQueryValueEx( hKey, dataKey, NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)data, &dataSize);

     // Breakpoint to see what ret and ret2 are equal to
     int j = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design.  The first call failed because you specified as size that was too small.  But what you didn't count on is that it **also** updated your dataSize variable.  To tell you how much memory to allocate so the call can succeed.

So the second call succeeded since you now specify a size that's *exactly* correct.  But without doing the *other* thing you needed to do, actually make the buffer bigger.  Nothing much good can happen when the call then causes a buffer overflow and corrupt your stack frame, be sure to use the /RTC compile option so you'll get a runtime error from that.

You avoided this problem by increasing the buffer size from 256 to 1024.  But your code is *still* incorrect, your program will fail miserably if the registry value ever gets larger than 1024 bytes.  Don't use a local array, use the *new* operator or malloc() to allocate the buffer so it can never fail like this.  Or simply fail the call and declare "bad data".

Also note another bug, the dataSize is in *bytes* but the buffer is TCHAR, not a byte.  Which is probably why you didn't corrupt the stack frame, the buffer was big enough by accident.  You don't want to rely on accidents like this.  Consider a helper class like CRegKey to avoid these kind of mistakes.

Comment: Thank you, I have at least fixed the buffer overflow problem I think. Right now I am making a first call to `RegQueryValueEx` to get the correct size in `dataSize`, then using the _new_ operator to allocate a `TCHAR` buffer the size of `dataSize`. Is this still a bug since as you state the `dataSize` is in bytes and the buffer is `TCHAR`, not a byte?

Comment: Yes.  You could punt the problem with malloc().